# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, aws-cli, amazon-polly

I am trying to resolve the dreaded SSL Certificate error:

.....CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
...........

when trying to validate a Polly endpoint, such as: https://polly.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/speech

triggers these errors:
--CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

-- CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)

................

I am doing this in the CLI in Windows using Python 3.10.2

..............
Scenario 1
I'm executing this code in the CLI
{{ python helloworld.py }}

which triggers this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tdrod\Wiley-Book\Online Material Chapter 1 Code\helloworld.py", line 10, in 
result = polly.synthesize_speech(Text='Hello World!',
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 391, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 725, in _make_request
return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 104, in make_request
return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 138, in _send_request
while self._needs_retry(attempts, operation_model, request_dict,
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 254, in _needs_retry
responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 357, in emit
return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 228, in emit
return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
response = handler(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 183, in **call**
if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 250, in **call**
should_retry = self._should_retry(attempt_number, response,
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 316, in **call**
checker_response = checker(attempt_number, response,
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 222, in **call**
return self._check_caught_exception(
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
raise caught_exception
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 201, in _do_get_response
http_response = self._send(request)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 270, in _send
return self.http_session.send(request)
File "C:\Users\tdrod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 430, in send
raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://polly.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/speech [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

---

### Scenario 2:

code executing at CLI:
aws polly put-lexicon --name awsLexicon --content file://aws-lexicon.xml

WHICH triggers this error:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)

---

I have noted and parsed through the many similar posts but have not found many that are as similar to this issue with AWS Polly and SSL

Among my steps tried so far was to update the certificate: @ CLI -> pip install certifi I And, verified in site-packages/certifi that 'cacert' is present

I'm sure I am missing some step(s). Can anyone see what I should do next?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try to add web site's CA certificate into Python's default certificate store?